# Server Sent Event isn't (flushing?) properly with Flask and Redis with nginx front

Tags: javascript, nginx, flask, redis, server-sent-events

I'm trying to stream call data from a PBX server. I have a Golang backend that receives this data and publishes it to a channel in Redis. The idea is to get realtime call data in a webapp.

This is composed of two Flask apps: One is the app itself. It's filled with api and ajax calls. The second is simply a route that streams the call data.

I had to split the apps in two due to deadlines to solve a problem with threading the main app and ajax calls.

To avoid CORS issues, I setup a nginx front. Here is my config:

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name <domain>;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
        location /stream {
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            expires off; # I set this trying to debug.
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the streaming code:

```
@app.route('/stream/', methods=['GET'])
def event_socket_stream():
    def event_stream():
        stream = redis.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
        stream.subscribe('eventsocket')
        for message in stream.listen():
            print(message)
            yield 'data: {}\n\n'.format(message['data'])

    return Response(event_stream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

I'm threading the above by by doing `threaded=True` in the `app.run()` call.

On the first app, I serve up some jQuery that uses the JavaScript SSE api:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Skipping above non-related functions.
    // Event Socket Stream
    var eventStream = new EventSource('/stream/');
    eventStream.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        fsEvent = JSON.parse(event.data);
        parseEvent(fsEvent);
    };
});
```

The problem occurs on both Chromium and Firefox. This event should be sent when I call the PBX, however, the first call is never sent. I can see the browser connecting to it when the page loads, though.

`GET XHR http://<domain>/stream/`

When I call the PBX, the browser receives aboslutely nothing. If I call it a second time, I see the call data that I should have received during the first call.

To illustrate:

*call* -> Nothing -> *call* -> *Call 1 Data* -> *call* -> *Call 2 Data*

This is why I call it a "flushing" problem. It looks like the stream isn't flushing the data when a call is received.

If I set `ignore_subscribe_messages=False`, then I receive the redis subscribe message upon the first call.

Also, if I kill the streaming app process, the browser receives the last event that should have been received.

Any solutions are 100% welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Nginx didn't have the needed headers to make it work. This got it working:

```
proxy_set_header Connection '';
proxy_http_version 1.1;
chunked_transfer_encoding off;
```

Now, all is well.

Thanks to friends in #redis on freenode!